# preventing too many database connections

Tags: php

I have an include file for my database connections that has the following code:

```
$my_db_link = mysql_connect('my_host', 'my_username', 'my_password');
if (!$my_db_link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$my_db_name = 'my_database';
mysql_select_db($my_db_name);
```

Will it make a difference if I use include_once() rather than include(), or require_once() rather than require()? We had a recent "too many connections" error ("PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Too many connections ") and I'm wondering if using include() created more connections than necessary.

```
include_once('my_db_connect.php');
```

instead of

```
include('my_db_connect.php');
```

Comment: You have two choices: never call that `include` more than once per page, or call `include_once` as many times you please.

Comment: you could maybe look into the singleton pattern and develop a database class for yourself.

Comment: @Dalton that's a bad idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323

Comment: @Gordon interesting.. thank you for the resource!

Comment: Here's the only thing that worked in our case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226015/error-too-many-connections-on-codeigniter-website

Answer (score 1):

> The require() function is identical to
>   include(), except that it handles
>   errors differently. If an error
>   occurs, the include() function
>   generates a warning, but the script
>   will continue execution. The require()
>   generates a fatal error, and the
>   script will stop.

The manual for require_once is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

> The require_once() statement is
>   identical to require() except PHP will
>   check if the file has already been
>   included, and if so, not include
>   (require) it again.

Using persistent connections can require a bit of tuning of your Apache and MySQL configurations to ensure that you do not exceed the number of connections allowed by MySQL.

So its better to use `mysql_pconnect()` to prevent over loading of connections. Check the manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)

Answer (score 1):

> Will it make a difference if I use include_once() rather than include(), or require_once() rather than require()?

In this circumstance, no.  However, in higher-performance applications, be careful about using include_once/require_once on some systems.  PHP uses a stat() call every time the *_once() function is used in your code to determine if it has included that file already or not.
If you are careful with your design, you'll avoid double-includes entirely; most higher-level PHP developers avoid it by using object-oriented programming mixed with just-in-time autoloading of class files.

edit: http://www.techyouruniverse.com/software/php-performance-tip-require-versus-require_once

Something to chew on for the bored. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mod_php, consider using [`mysql_pconnect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) for connection pooling.  More on connection persistence here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

Answer (score 0):

Using [`include_once`](http://php.net/include_once) instead of [`include`](http://php.net/include) will only avoid another include of the same file within the same runtime. Besides that, [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/mysql_connect) will already use already an existing connection if there is one with the same credentials.

But you could try [`mysql_pconnect`](http://php.net/mysql_pconnect) for persistent connections:

> `mysql_pconnect()` acts very much like `mysql_connect()` with two major differences.
>
> First, when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username and password. If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection.
>
> Second, the connection to the SQL server will not be closed when the execution of the script ends. Instead, the link will remain open for future use (`mysql_close()` will not close links established by `mysql_pconnect()`).